# How could I show only selected row in PHP?

Tags: php, mysql, row, selected

I'm working at this thing that takes information from a MySQL database that comes from a contact form and displays it all to the user. Well, I got that far without issues using:

```
 $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM contact");
 while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
   {
  echo $row['name'] . "<br/>" . "<a href=mailto:" . $row['email']. "> " . $row['email'] . "</a>";
  echo "<br/>";
  echo $row['message'];
  echo "<br />";
  }
```

Now I would like to add a button next to each item that would single them out, basically taking me to a page where only the selected row shows up, not all of them, as happens on this page.

The thing is that i don't know how to do that. So, does anyone have any ideas?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a button that refreshes the page with a "GET" parameter, such as `yourpage.php?uid=123`; Then do

```
if ($_GET['uid'] !== null) {
    $id = (int) $_GET['uid'];
    $result = mysql_query('SELECT * FROM contact WHERE id='.$id);
    ...
}
```